# How to create a velocity stack of maps in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, 3d, stack, slice

I have a dataset with velocity measurements during periods of earthquake:
[image: measurements dataset]

I want to create a stack of maps [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57502763/how-to-plot-horizontal-stack-of-heatmaps-or-a-stack-of-grid) so each slice is one month of my dataset. The color of the plots should be a color gradient based on the measurements of each month.

Any help is very welcome! I tried many codes without success.

Here are 2 subplots I have:

```py
# Normalize Earthquake Velocity values
normalized_velocity_earthquake_april = cumulative_velocity_yearpixel_EQnormalized['April']

# Normalize No Earthquake Velocity values
normalized_velocity_earthquake_sept = cumulative_velocity_yearpixel_EQnormalized['September']

# Create subplots for comparison
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(12, 6))

# Plot 1: April Velocity
sc1 = ax1.scatter(cumulative_velocity_yearpixel_EQnormalized['LON'], cumulative_velocity_yearpixel_EQnormalized['LAT'],
                  c=normalized_velocity_earthquake_april, cmap='RdYlGn') #norm=Normalize(-1, 1))
ax1.set_xlabel('Longitude')
ax1.set_ylabel('Latitude')
ax1.set_title('Earthquake Velocity (mm/day) - April')
fig.colorbar(sc1, ax=ax1, label='Earthquake Velocity (mm/day)')

# Plot 2: No Earthquake Velocity
sc2 = ax2.scatter(cumulative_velocity_yearpixel_EQnormalized['LON'], cumulative_velocity_yearpixel_EQnormalized['LAT'],
                  c=normalized_velocity_earthquake_sept, cmap='RdYlGn' )#norm=Normalize(-1, 1))
ax2.set_xlabel('Longitude')
ax2.set_ylabel('Latitude')
ax2.set_title('Earthquake Velocity - September (mm/yr)')
fig.colorbar(sc2, ax=ax2, label='Earthquake Velocity (mm/yr)')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I tried the following plot, but I don't want just a stack of scatter points. I want each individual slice as a map view figure and have them stacked per month across the z-axis.

```py
# Months list in your dataset
months_list = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

# Create a 3D figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Loop through each month and plot a scatter for each slice
for i, month in enumerate(months_list):
    x = cumulative_velocity_yearpixel_EQnormalized['LON']
    y = cumulative_velocity_yearpixel_EQnormalized['LAT']
    z = np.full_like(x, i)  # Z-value (depth) for the slice, using the index
    
# Extract the velocity values for the specific month
velocity = cumulative_velocity_yearpixel_EQnormalized[month]
    
# Scatter plot for the slice
ax.scatter(x, y, z, c=velocity, cmap='RdYlGn')  # Change the colormap if needed

# Customize labels and title
ax.set_xlabel('Longitude')
ax.set_ylabel('Latitude')
ax.set_zlabel('Month')
ax.set_zticks(np.arange(len(months_list)))
ax.set_zticklabels(months_list)

plt.title('Velocity Data Across Months')
#plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```